Is it possible to [sometimes] undo Lashon Hara?
If one spoke Lashon Hara to someone, and then realised and regretted it, can they go to that person and say "I know I said that, but I was wrong, it's not true, I was just in a bad mood and I spoke Lashon Hara, please don't believe it anymore" and potentially offer a second interpretation of what happened that is not Lashon Hara?
e.g. I said to my wife

This person doesn't know what they are talking about. They speak a lot but it's clear they don't really know what they are saying, they are just reguritating information.

Now, I look back, and I realise it was Lashon Hara. Should I go back to my wife and tell her

Actually, I was just in a bad mood, and it was Lashon Hara to say what I said, and for all I know, he does know what he is talking about and I was just being too harsh. Please pretend I never said it and let's both take on to show this person more respect in our hearts and our deeds.

This is assuming she hasn't told anyone else, in which case it will be a much bigger problem.
So, if yes, this is what one can/should do, it a complete rectification, or only partial? What else should one do when one has spoken Lashon Hara like this? Maybe they should go to the person and say what they said and ask for forgiveness, but I've heard that this isn't always the best thing to do, because it will add another sin on top of the previous one, by making them feel bad. But, there's also the side that says it's obligatory to get their forgiveness.
So, I hope my question is clear, let me know if I can sharpen it.

I really don't understand the question. How is this a halachic question? Do what you can to fix what you did wrong. What choices are you offering here?

@MichoelR ok I will remove the halacha tag, I am coming from the point of view of having absorbed all the scary mashalim like "the difficulty of undoing lashon hara is as hard as collecting feathers scattered in the wind", and looking to see if it's even possible to undo lashon hara completely, or partially, or at all. "Do what you can" is not going to be a valid answer to this question unless it literally is the only answer but I will still want some suggestions and some evidence towards how effective the suggestions are

I wasn't asking about the tag. I just don't see what the question is. Of course you should do what you can, and of course sometimes it works better or not.

See Chafetz Chayyim 1:4:12. (Also, one particular detail in this specific section happens to be controversial. See here.)
